# How to remove comments created automatically from t4toolbox？

Tags: javascript, t4-toolbox

I am using t4toolbox extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/791817a4-eb9a-4000-9c85-972cc60fd5aa) to output js file. But I find some text block auto-generated in js files as:

// 
//   This file was generated by T4 code generator XX.tt.
//   Any changes made to this file manually will be lost next time the file is regenerated.
//

This comment does not be supported for javascript syntax.
How to remove this text block from T4toolbox? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you found this one yourself, but it may prove useful to others.

In my template, all it took was remove or comment out the line

```
base.TransformText();
```

From the TransformText method. This solved the issue in my case.